# SQL Store Unknown Column Name in Variable from a Given Input

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to find a column name and store it as a variable based on a given input of information.  The information that I am passing into this routine is one piece of data that specifies which row to look at, and another piece of information that exists somewhere within that row.

What I want to do is find what column that second piece of data is in, store that column name in a variable and utilize it for other purposes.

I realize this code does not work however this is similar to what I am trying to do.

INPUT1 gets me to the correct row as the key and INPUT2 Gets me to the correct column, but how do I get the column name that INPUT2 is in?

```
DECLARE COLUMNNAME VARCHAR(45);
SET COLUMNAME = SELECT /*COLUMN NAME I AM LOOKING FOR*/
   FROM Table
   WHERE primary_key = INPUT1 AND /*unknown_column*/ = INPUT2;
```

Additionally, can I modify the information that I will have stored in COLUMNAME after it is retrieved.  Ex change table_page1 to table_page2?

If there is anyone who could help me with this I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do it, you need a `UNION` query like this:

```
SELECT "col1" columname
FROM Table
WHERE primary_key = input1 AND col1 = input2
UNION
SELECT "col2"
FROM Table
WHERE primary_key = input1 AND col2 = input2
UNION
SELECT "col3"
FROM Table
WHERE primary_key = input1 AND col3 = input2
and so on
```

You can create a dynamic query using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` that checks all the columns.

Comment: How does a dynamic query work?  To create the UNION of this table would be a massive effort because it is just slightly over 100 columns long.  If I were to UNION can I modify the information that I will have stored in COLUMNAME after it is retrieved. Ex change table_page1 to table_page2?  I am primarily a C++ person and could do  it there but I don't know if SQL supports such activities.

Comment: A dynamic query is a stored procedure that constructs the query to run. It can run a query against `information_schema` to get the column names, and loop over them to build all the subqueries in the union.

Comment: You can also do it in C++ -- write a query that gets the column names from information_schema, and builds a new query to run with `mysql_query()`.

Comment: Google "mysql dynamic sql" and you'll find lots of examples.